# "Insert in program" or "Include in program"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Is the usage of verb "insert" is correct in the following sentence? Shouldn't it be changed for "include"?

The Reduction of St. Michael was inserted in the vast program of evangelization of the Jesuits.

The text I'm working on is about Jesuit Missions in South America in 16-17th centuries.

Comment: What is the "reduction of St. Michael"?

Comment: It is a kind of village built by Jesuit in order to unite Indian tribes and create a community. It was located between the Spanish and Portuguese empires of 17th century.

Comment: And what is a “program of evangelization”?

Comment: The text was translated from portuguese by another person and I'm just making corrections. So, probably some other words should be changed also.

Comment: Either word could work. Can't tell much given  the context of one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be talking about [Jesuit reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesuit_reduction), i.e. the resettlement of indigenous South Americans into villages, in order to influence or control them more easily.

Presumably this particular quotation is related to what is now the city of [São Miguel das Missões](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Miguel_das_Miss%C3%B5es) (*St Michael of the Missions*) in Brazil.

You could try something like

> Resettlement to the mission of St. Michael was part of the vast program of Jesuit evangelization

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm talking about. Thank you very much!